# First Fundamental Theorem of Calculus question regarding F'(x)

Tags: calculus

The first fundamental theorem is defined:

$F(x) = \int^x_c f(t) dt$ where $c$ is constant.

The corollary:

$\int^b_a f(t) dt = F(b) - F(a)$

My question is how can the integral $[c, x]$ in the first theorem be calculated without the corollary?  Otherwise would $c$ be assumed to be $0$?

As an example:

$f(t) = t^2$,
$F(t) = \int^x_c f(t) dt = \int^x_c t^2 dt$

Antiderivative:
$F(t) = \frac {t^3} 3$

However, my understanding is the antiderivative is the area under the curve from $t = 0$.

Appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Are you sure the first theorem shouldn't be  $F(x)=\int f(x)~dx$?

Comment: In all generality $F(x)=\int_c^x f(t)dt+C$ since trying with f being 0 gives only 0 else for the area under f.

Comment: The antiderivative is not unique. $F(t) = \frac{t^3}{3}+5$ is also an antiderivative of $f(t)$. (adding any constant also gives an antiderivative).  And in this case $F(b)$ does not give the area under $f(t)$ from $t=0$ to $t=b$. $F(b)-F(0)$ gives that area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are skipping a step. The corollary can be stated:

For a function $F'(x)=f(x)$ (such a function is called an antiderivative)

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt=F(b)-F(a)$$

Hence it tells you that in order to calculate the definite integral you need to find an antiderivative $F$.

Comment: I'm following the steps at Wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus.  $F'(x) = f(x)$ where as I state above $F(x) = \int^x_a f(t) dt$.  My concern is regarding lower bound in the definite integral, $c$ in the first part.  For example if called $F(a)$.

Comment: @Nick, a is just a constant. The point is that a is fixed, whereas x is a variable.